# loading a view in popup

Tags: views

hi i'm trying to display a ***view*** in a *popup* but unable to get a solution. i tried

- colorbox node module
- popup views integration module

Is there any better way to display a view as a popup ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I need to display a `view` in popup, then I will use [ctools](https://drupal.org/project/ctools) module.
`Ctools` provide `Modal dialog` functionality to display element in `modal`.

You need to follow below step for the same:

- Create a custom module.
- Create `Menu item` which will interact with `ctools modal`.
- Define `ajax callback` for the menu item and return HTML of the modal using `ajax`.

You can check working example (http://deeson-online.co.uk/labs/insert-form-pop-modal-ctools-and-drupal-7)

Comment: good solution ,this is work (y)